# Avoid Android automatically re-add my fragment on orientation change

Tags: java, android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments

I have a `ListFragment` which depends on the hosting `Activity` to properly initialize. On first run, it loads up fine. Once I change the orientation, my app crashes. From the stack trace I can see it isn't me trying to add the `Fragment` prematurely, rather Android is trying to restore the `Fragment`.

I have `setRetainInstance(false)` set in the `onStart` method but can't find any method to disable the restoring of the `Fragment` once the orientation changes. Any ideas? Do I need to remove the `Fragment` prior to my app being destroyed?

Edit: I ended up delaying initializing the list until the Activity is ready. Android conveniently shows a 'loading' message until the adapter is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up delaying initializing the list until the Activity is ready. Android conveniently shows a 'loading' message until the adapter is set.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a ListFragment which depends on the hosting Activity to properly initialize.

That may be your difficulty right there.

> From the stack trace I can see it isn't me trying to add the Fragment prematurely, rather Android is trying to restore the Fragment.

Correct.

> Any ideas?

I would focus on handling configuration changes properly. Between `onSaveInstanceState()` in the fragment and the combination of `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`, `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` (both on `Activity`) and `onAttach()` (on your `Fragment`), you should be able to pass whatever stuff is in the old fragment to the new one without crashing. For configuration changes, do not rely upon "the hosting Activity to properly initialize".

Comment: Orientation changes are already handled gracefully by the Activity. The Fragment depends on the Activity because the Activity binds to a Service and gets info from there, which is used by the Fragment. Your suggestion seems, no offense intended, rather clunky. Unless anyone other ideas, I may just remove the Fragment at some stage before OnDestroy is called.

Comment: @Al: "Orientation changes are already handled gracefully by the Activity." -- clearly not, otherwise you would not have posted this question. "The Fragment depends on the Activity because the Activity binds to a Service and gets info from there, which is used by the Fragment." -- so? "Your suggestion seems, no offense intended, rather clunky." -- I would say the same about your current implementation. Beauty, as they say, is in the eye of the beholder.